# Asp.net membership

Tags: asp.net, sql, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

If I want to do an admin function like delete a user on the asp.net membership stuff that ships with the asp.net mvc sample.

I tried looking through the tables and realized that there was multiple tables that had rows added.  I assume there must be a simpler way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Membership provider there is a method:

```
public bool DeleteUser(string username, bool deleteAllRelatedData)
```

If this is the standard asp.net membership provider that method runs a stored proc that cleans the user from your DB.

Here is some more examples:
https://web.archive.org/web/20210304121422/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/091207-1.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Membership API's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998347.aspx#paght000022_membershipapis).

To delete a user, use the [Membership.DeleteUse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w6b0zxdw.aspx)r method

```
Membership.DeleteUser(User.Identity.Name, true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't delete direct from the database, go through the membership provider and call the [Membership.DeleteUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5xxz7y3a.aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

The Membership Provider [base class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx) has the methods you need. For example to delete a user you use the [DeleteUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.deleteuser.aspx) method. What you do NOT do is directly access the SQL database

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the ASP.NET Configuration Tool.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998347.aspx - Step 3 shows how to add users.  The same principle applies for deleting them.  You can also mark them as inactive instead of deleting them.  I usually mark them as inactive to preserve my database relationships.